# How to refresh data in angularjs kendo-multi-select

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-scope, kendo-mobile, angularjs-model

I am new to angularjs. i am using kendo multiselect i am adding data by default when loading the view. and i have one save button when click that button i am calling Success method inside that method.

Inside that method i am trying to replace another data into that multiselect. Scope is updating fine, But multiselect textbox showing empty. not showing the data.

```
$scope.Details.EmailIDs = [
  { "Selected": false, "Text": "sample1", "Value": "sample1@gamil.com" },
  { "Selected": false, "Text": "sample2", "Value": "Sample2@gmail.com" }
];

$scope.ButtonClick = function () {
 $scope.Success();
}

$scope.Success = function () 
 {
   $scope.Details.EmailIDs = [
   { "Selected": false, "Text": "data1", "Value": "data1@jaajitech.com" },
   { "Selected": false, "Text": "data2", "Value": "data2@jaajitech.com"}
        ];
 }
```

here is my html code

```
     <select kendo-multi-select k-options="UserOptions" k-value-primitive="false" k-ng-model="Details.EmailIDs"></select>
     <button class="k-button" ng-click="ButtonClick()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Adding data to an array? I don't see push or unshift

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding rather replacing value, to add use like this

```
$scope.Success = function () 
 {
 $scope.Details.EmailIDs.push({ "Selected": false, "Text": "data1", "Value": "data1@jaajitech.com" });
 $scope.Details.EmailIDs.push({ "Selected": false, "Text": "data2", "Value": "data2@jaajitech.com"});
}
```

Comment: Suppose If i want to replace ?